# Speeding up planet generation and avoiding for loops in R

Tags: r, math, vector, graphics, data-visualization

I'm working on a little program that's supposed to be used in calculating surface solar irradiance of a planet, specifically Mars. Eventually, I want to be able to enter a date/time range and coordinates and have the program graph me that specific location's solar irradiance. I decided to use R because it's good at graphing and large datasets.

Here's my code so far:

```
longitudePoints <- 97 #How many points on the circle
latitudePoints <- 97 #How many latitudes there are

sunAngle <- 323 #angle between planetary axis and sun
dayAngle <- 123   #angle of mars on it's axis (1 rotation per mars day)

#Surface of sphere Coordinates
X <- vector(mode="double", length=longitudePoints*latitudePoints)
Y <- vector(mode="double", length=longitudePoints*latitudePoints)
Z <- vector(mode="double", length=longitudePoints*latitudePoints)
#Surface Sun Vector components
Xsun <- vector(mode="double", length=longitudePoints*latitudePoints)
Ysun <- vector(mode="double", length=longitudePoints*latitudePoints)
Zsun <- vector(mode="double", length=longitudePoints*latitudePoints)
#Latitude Logitude mapping
LatPos <- vector(mode="double", length=longitudePoints*latitudePoints)
LonPos <- vector(mode="double", length=longitudePoints*latitudePoints)
localMag <- vector(mode="double", length=longitudePoints*latitudePoints)


for(l in 0:latitudePoints) {
  for(i in 1:longitudePoints) {
    X[i+longitudePoints * (l)] <- sin( ( 2 * 3.1415 )/longitudePoints * i) * sin( (3.1415 )/latitudePoints * (l))
    Y[i+longitudePoints * (l)] <- cos( ( 2 * 3.1415 )/longitudePoints * i) * sin( (3.1415 )/latitudePoints * (l))
    Z[i+longitudePoints * (l)] <- cos( (3.1415 )/latitudePoints * (l))
    LonPos[i+longitudePoints * (l)] <- (i-1) * 360/longitudePoints
    LatPos[i+longitudePoints * (l)] <- (l * 180/latitudePoints) -90
  }
}

northPole <- c(X[1],Y[1],2 * Z[1])
southPole <- c(X[length(X)],Y[length(Y)],2 * Z[length(Z)])

#Perform Mars point rotations

#Apply inclination
Rx_theta <- -3.1415/2 - 25 * 3.1415/180

Rx <- matrix( c(1,0,0,0,cos(Rx_theta),-sin(Rx_theta),0,sin(Rx_theta),cos(Rx_theta)),nrow = 3,ncol = 3,byrow = TRUE)

for( i in 1:length(X)){
  tempPointVector <- c(X[i],Y[i],Z[i])
  tempPointVector <- tempPointVector %*% Rx
  X[i] <- tempPointVector[1]
  Y[i] <- tempPointVector[2]
  Z[i] <- tempPointVector[3]
}
northPole <- northPole %*% Rx
southPole <- southPole %*% Rx

#apply Day rotation
Ry_theta <- dayAngle * 3.1415/180

Ry <- matrix( c( cos(Ry_theta),0,sin(Ry_theta),0,1,0,-sin(Ry_theta),0,cos(Ry_theta) ),nrow = 3,ncol = 3,byrow = TRUE)
for( i in 1:length(X)){
  tempPointVector <- c(X[i],Y[i],Z[i])
  tempPointVector <- tempPointVector %*% Ry
  X[i] <- tempPointVector[1]
  Y[i] <- tempPointVector[2]
  Z[i] <- tempPointVector[3]
}
northPole <- northPole %*% Ry
southPole <- southPole %*% Ry



## Add the sun
sunP1 <- c(6,0,0)
sunP2 <- c(3,0,0)
sunNorm <- c(1,0,0)
sunLight <- c(10,0,0)

scalar1 <- function(x) {x / sqrt(sum(x^2))}
magnit1 <- function(x) {sqrt(sum(x^2))}
sunAngle <- (sunAngle + 90)*3.1415/180

Sun_Ry <- matrix( c( cos(sunAngle),0,sin(sunAngle),0,1,0,-sin(sunAngle),0,cos(sunAngle) ),nrow = 3,ncol = 3,byrow = TRUE)
sunP1 <- sunP1 %*% Sun_Ry
sunP2 <- sunP2 %*% Sun_Ry
sunNorm <- sunNorm %*% Sun_Ry
sunLight <- sunLight %*% Sun_Ry


for(i in 1:length(X)){
  surfP <- c(X[i],Y[i],Z[i])
  tempPointVector <- surfP * sunNorm
  
  surfPmag <- sqrt(sum(tempPointVector^2))
  tempPointVector <- sunNorm * surfPmag

  if( magnit1(surfP+tempPointVector) > magnit1(surfP) ){
    Xsun[i] <- (X[i] + tempPointVector[1]) 
    Ysun[i] <- (Y[i] + tempPointVector[2])
    Zsun[i] <- (Z[i] + tempPointVector[3])
    localMag[i] <- magnit1(surfP+tempPointVector)
 }else{
    Xsun[i] <- (X[i]) 
    Ysun[i] <- (Y[i])
    Zsun[i] <- (Z[i])
    localMag[i] <- 0
  }
}
```

And the code for the visualizations:

```
#Visualizations
if(TRUE){
  rgl.open()
  clear3d(type = "light")
  rgl.points(X,Y,Z, color="red")
  rgl.spheres(0,0,0,r=1,color="orange")
  arrow3d(northPole,southPole, type="lines", color="white",s=0.1)
  arrow3d(sunP1,sunP2, type="extrusion", color="yellow")
  arrow3d(c(0,0,0),c(sunNorm[1],sunNorm[2],sunNorm[3]), type="extrusion", color="yellow")
  
  rgl.bbox(color=c("#333377","black"), emission="#333377",
           specular="#3333FF", shininess=5, alpha=0.8 ) 
  
  rgl.lines(2*c(0, max(X)), c(0, 0), c(0, 0), color = "red")
  rgl.lines(c(0, 0), 2*c(0,max(Y)), c(0, 0), color = "green")
  rgl.lines(c(0, 0), c(0, 0), 2*c(0,max(Z)), color = "blue")
  
  segments3d(x=t(cbind(X,Xsun)),y=t(cbind(Y,Ysun)),z=t(cbind(Z,Zsun)), color="white")
  
  
  rgl.light(x=sunLight[1],y=sunLight[2],z=sunLight[3],viewpoint.rel = FALSE, ambient = "#FFFFFF", 
            diffuse = "#FFFFFF", specular = "#FFFFFF",)
}

x_coord <- LonPos
y_coord <- LatPos
value <- localMag
foo <- data.frame(x_coord, y_coord, value)
library(MBA)
foo=foo[ order(foo[,1], foo[,2],foo[,3]), ]
mba.int <- mba.surf(foo, 100, 100, extend=T)$xyz.est
library(fields)
fields::image.plot(mba.int, ylim = c(-90,90), yaxp = c(-90,90,12), xaxp = c(0,360,12))
title(main="Mars Solar Irradiance",
      xlab="Longitude (degrees)", ylab="Latitude (degrees)")
```

Essentially, the code:

1. Generates the points on an "UV" sphere using trigonometry
2. Uses rotational matrices to set the planet's inclination and rotation
3. Creates sun vectors and rotates them properly
4. Using vector math, calculate how much sun hits each point

This can then be graphed into a neat graph like so:

[image: Mars solar Irradiance]

Or into a neat 3d-representation like so:

[image: 3d visualization]

**My questions:**

- I've read that R is not designed to work well with loops. How would I go about replacing them in my code?
- Is there a better or faster way to populate the list of points on my sphere?
- Is R the right programming language for what I'm trying to?

---

*Note: Most of my programming knowledge is general, and I'm an absolute R amateur.*

---

I've rewritten and updated my code with some optimizations:

```
    library(rgl)

print("Sphere generation:")
print(system.time({
#Inputs ----
lat_divs <- 1000
lon_divs <- 1000
p_radius <- 1
day_angle <- 0
year_angle <- 0

#Scaffolding for polar sphere coordinates ----
lat_angles <- seq(from = pi/(-1+lat_divs), to = pi-pi/(-1+lat_divs), by = pi/(-1+lat_divs))
lon_angles <- seq(from = 0, to = 2*pi-2*pi/lon_divs, by = 2*pi/lon_divs)

#Generate Sphere Points and Lat/Lons ----
p_X <- as.vector(p_radius*tcrossprod(sin(lat_angles),cos(lon_angles)))
p_Y <- as.vector(p_radius*tcrossprod(cos(lat_angles),rep(1,lon_divs)))
p_Z <- as.vector(p_radius*tcrossprod(sin(lat_angles),sin(lon_angles)))
p_lats <- as.vector(tcrossprod(seq(from = -90+180/(lat_divs-1), to = 90-180/(lat_divs-1), by = 180/(lat_divs-1)),rep(1,lon_divs)))
p_lons <- as.vector(tcrossprod(rep(1,lat_divs-2),seq(from = -180, to = 180-360/lon_divs, by = 360/lon_divs)))
}))

print("Pole appending:")
print(system.time({
#Append north and south pole points
p_X <- c(p_X, c(0,0))
p_Z <- c(p_Z, c(0,0))
p_Y <- c(p_Y, c(p_radius,-p_radius))
p_lons <- c(p_lons, c(0,0))
p_lats <- c(p_lats, c(-90,90))
}))

print("Rotation Op1:")
print(system.time({
#Rotate the planet along the Y-axis to set it's time of day ----
Ry_theta <- day_angle * pi/180
Ry <- matrix( c( cos(Ry_theta),0,sin(Ry_theta),0,1,0,-sin(Ry_theta),0,cos(Ry_theta) ),nrow = 3,ncol = 3,byrow = TRUE)

mat = t(apply(cbind(p_X, p_Y, p_Z), 1L, `%*%`, Ry))
}))
print("Rotation Op2:")
print(system.time({
#Rotate the planet along the Z-axis to set the inclination of mars ----
Rz_theta <- -25 * pi/180
Rz <- matrix( c(cos(Rz_theta),-sin(Rz_theta),0,sin(Rz_theta),cos(Rz_theta),0,0,0,1),nrow = 3,ncol = 3,byrow = TRUE)

mat = t(apply(mat, 1L, `%*%`, Rz))
}))
print("Rotation Op3:")
print(system.time({
#Rotate the planet again along the Y-axis to set time of year ----
Ry_year <- year_angle * pi/180
Ry_year <- matrix( c( cos(Ry_year),0,sin(Ry_year),0,1,0,-sin(Ry_year),0,cos(Ry_year) ),nrow = 3,ncol = 3,byrow = TRUE)

mat = t(apply(mat, 1L, `%*%`, Ry_year))
}))
#Create the sun ----
sun_v  <- c(1,0,0) #Is a unit vector

print("Sun Math:")
print(system.time({
#Calculate the sun surface normal ----
sun_mat = t(apply(mat, 1L, `*`, sun_v)) + mat

#Filter out those which are negative
for(i in 1:length(p_X)){
  if(sun_mat[i] < 0){
    sun_mat[i,] <- sun_mat[i,] - sun_mat[i,]
  }
}

#Create a scalar vector for sun intensities
sun_vec <- sun_mat[,1]/2


}))


#Visualization 3d ----
if(FALSE){
  rgl.open()

  rgl.points(mat[,1],mat[,2],mat[,3], color="red")
  rgl.points(sun_mat[,1],sun_mat[,2],sun_mat[,3], color="white")
  #rgl.bbox(color=c("#333377","black"), emission="#333377",specular="#3333FF", shininess=5, alpha=0.8 ) 
  #northpole <- mat[length(p_X)-1,]*1.5
  #southpole <- mat[length(p_X),]*1.5
  
  arrow3d(p0 = c(-2,-2,-2), p1 = c(2,-2,-2), type = "rotation", color = "red")
  arrow3d(p0 = c(-2,-2,-2), p1 = c(-2,2,-2), type = "rotation", color = "green")
  arrow3d(p0 = c(-2,-2,-2), p1 = c(-2,-2,2), type = "rotation", color = "blue")
  #spheres3d(0,0,0, p_radius, color = "orange")
  #arrow3d(p0 = southpole, p1 = northpole, type = "line", color = "white", barblen = p_radius/25)
  text3d(3,-2,-2, text = "X-axis", color = "red")
  text3d(-2,3,-2, text = "Y-axis", color = "green")
  text3d(-2,-2,3, text = "Z-axis", color = "blue")
}

#Visualization 2d ----
if(FALSE){
  vis2d <- data.frame(p_lons, p_lats, sun_vec)
  library(MBA)
  vis2d = vis2d [ order(vis2d[,1], vis2d[,2],vis2d[,3]), ]
  mba.int <- mba.surf(vis2d, 100, 100, extend=T)$xyz.est
  library(fields)
  fields::image.plot(mba.int, ylim = c(-90,90), yaxp = c(-90,90,12), xaxp = c(-180,180,12))
  title(main="Mars Solar Irradiance",
        xlab="Longitude (degrees)", ylab="Latitude (degrees)")
}
```

Comment: how many latitude&longitude points do you eventually intend to calculate? With 97, calculation takes less than 1s, so loops are a perfectly legitimate choice. Looking at the results you allreay achieved, I think you already have a beginning of answer to your third question ;)

Comment: @Waldi well, eventually I want to import actual topological data to offset the surface in order to account for craters, mountains, and other surface features. When I do so, I think I'll need at least an order of magnitude more latitudinal and longitudinal points

Comment: I tried with 1000 * 1000 points, calculation time is below 10s : do you see a need for optimization? Now if you tell 10000*10000, I'm with you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code you provided is generally sound. We can try to rely more on [r](/questions/tagged/r) to do more accounting as well as putting some of your vectors into a single matrix.

The first optimization is `outer(...)`. This allows us to quickly allocate memory and use vectorization. This is 40x quicker on a 1000 x 1000 data creation. But... it is a little bit more of an eyesore.

```r
system.time({
X2 <- c(t(outer(0:latitudePoints, 
                     1:longitudePoints,
                     FUN = function(l, i) sin( ( 2 * 3.1415 )/longitudePoints * i) * sin( (3.1415 )/latitudePoints * (l))))
)
Y2 <- c(t(outer(0:latitudePoints, 
                     1:longitudePoints,
                     FUN = function(l, i) cos( ( 2 * 3.1415 )/longitudePoints * i) * sin( (3.1415 )/latitudePoints * (l))))
)

Z2 <- c(t(outer(0:latitudePoints, 
                     1:longitudePoints,
                     FUN = function(l, i) cos( (3.1415 )/latitudePoints * (l))))
)

Lon2 <- c(t(outer(0:latitudePoints, 
                1:longitudePoints,
                FUN = function(l, i) (i-1) * 360/longitudePoints
)))

Lat2 <- c(t(outer(0:latitudePoints, 
                  1:longitudePoints,
                  FUN = function(l, i) (l * 180/latitudePoints) -90
)))

})

## Timings for 1000 X 1000:

##   user  system elapsed 
##   0.22    0.00    0.22 

## Original Loop timing:
system.time({
for(l in 0:latitudePoints) {
    for(i in 1:longitudePoints) {
        X[i+longitudePoints * (l)] <- sin( ( 2 * 3.1415 )/longitudePoints * i) * sin( (3.1415 )/latitudePoints * (l))
        Y[i+longitudePoints * (l)] <- cos( ( 2 * 3.1415 )/longitudePoints * i) * sin( (3.1415 )/latitudePoints * (l))
        Z[i+longitudePoints * (l)] <- cos( (3.1415 )/latitudePoints * (l))
        LonPos[i+longitudePoints * (l)] <- (i-1) * 360/longitudePoints
        LatPos[i+longitudePoints * (l)] <- (l * 180/latitudePoints) -90
    }
}
})

##   user  system elapsed 
##   8.61    0.00    8.70
```

The next thing we can do is replace some of your `tempPointVectors` with a matrix and `apply()`. This is around 60% faster thankfully is more concise code writing:

```
system.time({mat = apply(cbind(X, Y, Z), 1L, `%*%`, Rx)})

##   user  system elapsed 
##   2.22    0.00    2.26 

system.time({
for( i in 1:length(X)){
    tempPointVector <- c(X[i],Y[i],Z[i])
    tempPointVector <- tempPointVector %*% Rx
    X[i] <- tempPointVector[1]
    Y[i] <- tempPointVector[2]
    Z[i] <- tempPointVector[3]
}
})

##   user  system elapsed 
##   3.77    0.00    3.79
```

And regarding your questions:

1. *R is bad at loops - how to replace?* R is ok at loops - it mainly becomes memory inefficient. But as you get into a million rows to loop through, [rcpp](/questions/tagged/rcpp) which would have code very similar to what you have and is super fast (I've included a portion below).
2. *Is there a better way to make the sphere?* I wish I knew. It almost seems like there is some type of linear algebra optimization but I am not familiar enough with it to figure it out.
3. *Is R the right tool for this?* Yes. R is great!

[rcpp](/questions/tagged/rcpp) snippet, I might try to do everything as I am trying to practice Rcpp more:

```cpp
#include <Rcpp.h>
using namespace Rcpp;

// [[Rcpp::export]]
Rcpp::List Rcpp_alt(const int longN, const int latN, const int sunAngle, const int dayAngle) {
    int n = longN * (latN + 1);
// Surface of sphere Coordinates
    NumericVector X = no_init(n);
    NumericVector Y = no_init(n);
    NumericVector Z = no_init(n);
// Surface Sun Vector components
//    NumericVector Xsun = no_init(n); // <- vector(mode="double", length=longN*latN);
//    NumericVector Ysun = no_init(n); // <- vector(mode="double", length=longN*latN)
//    NumericVector Zsun = no_init(n); //<- vector(mode="double", length=longN*latN)
// #Latitude Logitude mapping
    NumericVector LatPos = no_init(n); 
    NumericVector LonPos = no_init(n); 
//    NumericVector localMag = no_init(n); // <- vector(mode="double", length=longN*latN)
    
    for(int l = 0; l <= latN ; l++) {
        for(int i = 1; i <= longN; i++) {
            int ind = i + longN * l - 1; // 0 based index so minus 1
            X[ind] = sin( ( 2 * 3.1415 )/longN * i) * sin( (3.1415 )/latN * (l));
            Y[ind] = cos( ( 2 * 3.1415 )/longN * i) * sin( (3.1415 )/latN * (l));
            Z[ind] = cos( (3.1415 )/latN * (l));
            LonPos[ind] = (i-1) * 360/(double)longN;
            LatPos[ind] = (l * 180/(double)latN) -90;
        }
    }
    
    return(List::create(X, Y, Z, LonPos, LatPos));
}
```

```r
system.time(tmp <- Rcpp_alt(longitudePoints, latitudePoints, sunAngle, dayAngle))

##   user  system elapsed 
##   0.06    0.00    0.06 

## TRUE for all when we first initialize the X, Y, and Z variables.
all.equal(tmp[[1]], X)
all.equal(tmp[[2]], Y)
all.equal(tmp[[3]], Z)
all.equal(tmp[[4]], LonPos)
all.equal(tmp[[5]], LatPos)
```

Comment: Thanks for the input! Your comment about linear algebra got me thinking and I got the sphere-point-generation going very fast (only 0.2 sec for a 2k x 2k sphere) and using apply for the rotations also helped. Right now those seem to be the new bottleneck.

Comment: Not that you have to, but it seems like my answer led you to the right path. You can feel free to select it - I think that without a bounty you are unlikely to receive any additional solutions, let alone something with [tag:Rcpp]